# How to select particular <tr> data on clicking a <td>?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<div id="test">          
<tr>
               <td><input name="item" type="checkbox" value="foo1"></td>

                <td>foo2</td>

                <td>foo3 </td>

                <td><a href="#test" rel="facebox">edit</a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><input name="item" type="checkbox" value="bar1"></td>
                <td>bar2</td>
                <td>bar3 </td>
                <td><a href="#test" rel="facebox">edit</a></td>
              </tr>          

        </div>
```

Here I have two `<tr> ie two rows.` I have a `edit link` on the last `<td> of each <tr>.` I want that on clicking each `edit link` the particular tr data pop up with `facebox`. But I have no clue how to catch the only `one tr value?`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have a `tr` as a child of a `div`. Different browsers **will** recover from this error in different ways.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `<tr>` from [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), like this:

```
$("tr a").click(function() { 
  var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
});
```

Then you can do whatever you want with it, use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get contents, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr").each(function(i, el) {
  $(el).find("a").click(function(ev) { 
     var tr = el;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nick's solution will work with your sample code, but if there's a likelihood of any other a tags within td's in that tr, you'll want to be more specific:

```
$("a[rel=facebox]").click(function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    //do stuff with…
});
```

HTH

Blessings,
Jim Bob